# $3 \sin x + 4 \cos y = 5$, $4 \sin y + 3 \cos x = 2$ How to find $\sin x$, $\sin y$, $\cos x$, $\cos y$, 2020 contest question

Tags: trigonometry

https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2020/2020CSMC.pdf
https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2020/2020CSMCSolution.pdf

Question 5 from 2020 CSMC math contest:

$$3 \sin x + 4 \cos y = 5,$$ $$4 \sin y + 3 \cos x = 2.$$

Find $\sin(x+y)$.

The solution page added that it is also possible to find $\sin x$, $\sin y$, $\cos x$, $\cos y$ with a different approach but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Square these equations and add them, using sin^2 t + cos^2t=1, sin a cos b + cos s sin b =sin(a+b) you get it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the contest solution page also said it is possible to find each of sin x, sin y, cos x, cos y, which is where I am having a hard time

Answer (score 1):

We have $4\cos y=5-3\sin x$.  Similarly we have $4\sin y=2-3\cos x$.  Squaring and add:
$$
16=(5-3\sin x)^2+(2-3\cos x)^2=38-30\sin x-12\cos x
$$
so $15\sin x+6\cos x=11$
which gives you possible $\sin x,\cos x$ (i.e., solve the system $15\sin x+6\cos x=11, \sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$ to get $\sin x=\frac{55\pm 4\sqrt{35}}{87}$, and similar for $\cos x$, or solve for $\tan\frac12x=\frac{15\pm 2\sqrt{35}}{17}$) and hence $\sin y,\cos y$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: starting with $\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y=\frac{1}{6}$ and using that $\cos y=\frac{5-3\sin x}{4}$, $\sin y=\frac{2-3\cos x}{4}$ we can obtain
$$ \sin x \cdot (5-3\sin x)+\cos x \cdot (2-3\cos x)=\frac{2}{3}$$
$$ 5\sin x+2\cos x =\frac{11}{3} \implies \cos x=\frac{11}{6}-2.5\sin x $$We also have that $\cos^2 x+\sin^2x=1$ 
Substitute $\cos x$ and solve quadratic to find $\sin x$.